# How to invert y axis in subplot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I am trying to make a subplot of three figures. All of the figures should have inverted y-axes. But when I use ´gca().invert_yaxis()´ it only inverts the last of the three subplots and not the first two. How can I invert all of the y axes?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import numpy as np

# Create the subplot
axes,(p1,p2, p3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)

# Temperature proxies
p1.plot(Ti/Mg, xrf_depth) 
p1.set_title("Clastic influx (Ti/Mg) and Ti (ppm)")
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

p2.plot(Ti/1000, xrf_depth)
ax = plt.gca()


p3.plot(Ca/Si, xrf_depth, '-g')
p3.set_title("Primary production (Ca/Si")


plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like you probably also want sharey =True in your subplots call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.gca()` literally means "get current axes", so it makes sense that only the last one is affected. In your case, the three axes are `p1,p2, p3`, therefore `p1.invert_yaxis()` etc. should do the job. Delete all lines containing `gca()` in your code.